# How to adjust process on responsive

Tags: html, css

I have designed the view for desktop but don't understand how to fix it on responsive... I have used only css for design... plz help with your suggestions.

Here is CodePen example https://codepen.io/sheetalsinghwd/pen/BaavJBB

```
.our-process-diagram{ position:relative; padding:10px; height:500px;}
.blue-circle { position:absolute; left:-190px; top:100px; width:55%; height:300px; border-radius:180px;
border: 20px solid #ff0000;}

.step, .step-down{ position:absolute; width:52px; height:52px; border:2px solid #000; border-radius:50px; text-align:center;
}

.step:before{ content:''; position:absolute; width:1px; height:40px; border-left:1px dashed green; bottom: -40px; left:auto; right:auto;}

.step:after{ content:''; display:block; width:20px; height:20px; background:#fff; border-radius:50px; bottom:-56px; position:absolute; left:16px;}

.step-down:after{content:''; position:absolute; width:1px; height:40px; border-left:1px dashed green; top: -40px; left:auto; right:auto;}

.step-down:before{ content:''; display:block; width:20px; height:20px; background:#fff; border-radius:50px; top:-56px; position:absolute; left:16px; z-index:100;}

.step-1{ left:5%}
.step-2{ left:20%;}
.step-3{ left:35%;  top:25px}
.step-3:before{ left:35%; transform:rotate(10deg);}
.step-3:after{left:3px;}

.step-4{ left:44.5%; top:130px}
.step-4:before{ transform:rotate(50deg); left:-10px; top:40px}
.step-4:after{ left:-44px; top:68px;}

.step-8{ left:5%; bottom:-10px}
.step-5{ left:20%; bottom:-10px}

.step-6{ left:35%; transform:rotate(-20deg); bottom:0px}
.step-7{ left:45%;bottom:130px}
.step-7:after{  transform:rotate(-50deg); left: -26%; top: -24px;} 
.step-7:before{  left: -47px; top: -32px;}

span p{ position:relative; top:-35px; left:auto; right:auto;}

.step-3 p{ left:15px;}

.step-4 p{ left:35px;}
```

Comment: @Akshay Bande the process diagram According to me is quite big which will not be adjusted on mobile... so can you suggest something that can be made out of this design n can be adjusted on mobile

Comment: Normally when you want to make stuff responsive, it helps using % values, because then it doesn't matter what size your screen is. I will try play around with the codepen

Comment: @chris i guess this diagram will not fit on mobile... i will try making this for mobile as a simple content one below another n hide other part... I think that will work.

Comment: What is your end goal? Did you want to make these clickable or move with animation? Because I think you will have a lot easier time just making an image and exporting it as a svg or even doing this in canvas.

Comment: I have to make it clickable.. and will also add animation... every circle will come one after another....  i will try this as svg also.. thanxxx

Comment: Sure it might not fit vertically, but if they change their view to horizontally it will be fine. You could even have it in a 100% width container and on click enlarge it so they can scroll around

Comment: @Akshay Bande I am avoiding Bootstrap frame for this diagram as bootstrap has some limitations...

Comment: @Chris if you try this plz forward me the link after you complete.. thanx

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203373/discussion-between-chris-and-ms-designer).